# Accessing IFrame

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, cross-domain

When I try to access the iframe, I get this error and I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. Can someone help me out with this problem?

```
var ifrm = document.getElementById('iframe'),
ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow :
                              (ifrm.contentDocument.document)
                            ? ifrm.contentDocument.document :
                              ifrm.contentDocument;

ifrm.open();
ifrm.write("Hello World!");
ifrm.close();
```

These are the errors I recieve:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined*

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'readyState' of undefined*

Comment: ***Cannot read property 'document' of undefined*** is pretty clear

Comment: `iframe.contentWindow` is not cross-browser?

Comment: On a side note: Say "No" to nested ternary operators.

Comment: I assume `ifrm` is a reference to an iframe node (like `var ifrm = document.querySelector('iframe')` for example). In that case you can have: `ifrm.contentDocument` or `ifrm.contentWindow.document`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the DOM element:

```
<iframe>
```

iframe is the name of an HTML tag, not the value of the id of this element (which would be defined as id="value") so you want to use:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
```

Change the 0 to whatever index is desired if there are multiple iframes on your page as getElementsByTagName() will return an array of results, even if there is only one iframe on the page.

Furthermore, you can simplify your ternary operation as follows:

```
ifrm = ifrm.contentWindow ? ifrm.contentWindow.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
```

This way you can obtain the document object for the iframe in all browsers which will give you access to the open(), write(), and close() methods as well as the readyState attribute.

Comment: thanks... much good! try too use ID is best, parent.document.getElementById( XXXX ); not need [0] ;-)

Comment: Agreed. Using an ID is better as you can be more sure that you are retrieving the element you actually want.

Answer (score 2):

put javascript source after  tag.

like this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<iframe>
<script>
blah blah
</script>
</body>
</html>
```